# How to call a Spring managed object from a POJO?

Tags: java, spring, pojo, applicationcontext

I am running a web-app, which has one exposed class ( available to other POJO classes) and that has one autowired private member.

> Spring managed class

```
public class EPSQueueSender {
   @Autowired
   private AmqpTemplate epsMessageTemplate;

   public void dosomething(...){
     epsMessageTemplate.convertAndSend(...); // Here epsMessageTemplate is null if instance of EPSQueueSender taken from other POJO 
   }
}
```

> POJO class

```
   public class Test{
       EPSQueueSender sender = new EPSQueueSender();
       sender.dosomething(....); // gives null exception on epsMessageTemplate
   }
```

Spring code ( running as WebApp) and POJO class code( different Jar) are on same JVM. The POJO is not able to get initialized autowired object. However it is initialized if I use it in webApp project.

Can someone please give some suggestion how can I overcome this problem?
Last thing I would like to try is to hit webserver as http request from POJO.

Comment: How do you expect spring to inject mesageTemplate? Have you defined beans in xml or you relying on spring 4?

Comment: It is defined in xml and xml is imported from servlet. So this bean is properly autowired and initialized at spring side code

Comment: How do you instantiate this call? Is it by Spring? Can you share your spring config?

Answer (score 0):

[beans](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html) can be pojo or xml many [examples](https://spring.io/guides) might help. You already have @autowired but you did not create the @bean method itself that belongs in a class annotated with @Configuration

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be overcome using @Configurable feature of spring. For it you have configure in xml with a code like belove

```
<context:annotation-config/>

    <context:spring-configured/>
    <context:load-time-weaver/>
```

in Java Congiguration like below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
public class ConfigApplicationContext {
}
```

with this configuration you can benefit of the load-waving aspect technique that througth the build-in Spring bean AnnotationBeanConfigureAspect you can inject Spring bean in a pojo that is annotated with @Configurable. you colud be have a code like below:

```
@Configurable
 public class Test{

    @Autowired
    private EPSQueueSender sender;


     public void method(){
       sender.dosomething(....); // gives null exception on epsMessageTemplate

    }
  }
```

of course, since that you are using a load-wave technique you have configure an agent that will perform the istruments. the configuration is very simple and you have add a line like below in the start of the jvm or tomcat:

java -javaagent:path of the jar with the agent/spring-instrument.jar

remember of course of insert the aop and spring aop maven dependency:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>yourVersion</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>4
      <version>yourVersion</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
      <version>yourVersion</version>
  </dependency>
```

I hope that this can help you